# How come I get childhood takes no arguments when I execute it but when I delete school in string q then it there comes NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, self

When I execute this code with q = childhood(school) I get no childhood takes no arguments
But when I execute without it they say intelligent isn't defined
I tried to make __init(self, intelligent) to solve it but it only makes it worse.
So I am wondering what am I doing wrong in this code?

```
from ex45f import live
class childhood(live):

    def development(self):
        intelligent["low", "average", "high"]
        if random.choice(intelligent) == low:
            return "You are dumb"
        elif random.choice(intelligent) == average:
            return "You are average"
        else:
            return "You are smart"

        if school == "yes" and intelligent == high:
            return 'You will have an fantastic life'
        elif school == "no" and intelligent == high:
            return "You will have an average life"
        elif school == "maybe" and intelligent == high:
            return "You will have an good life"
        elif school == "yes" and intelligent == average:
            return "You will have an good life"
        elif school == "no" and intelligent == average:
            return "You will have an bad life"
        elif school == "maybe" and intelligent == average:
            return "You will have an average life"
        elif school == "yes" and intelligent == low:
            return "You will have an average life"
        elif school == "no" and intelligent == low:
            return "You will have an horrible life"
        else:
            return "You will have an bad life"
#Zoek op how random choice antwoord bij betrekt
like_school = """Do you like school?
Possible answers: yes, no or maybe
> """
school = input(like_school)
q = childhood(school)
q.development()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what you have passed in the class as a superclass is a class and create a constructor(**init**) with the required arguments as self and school and assign school to self.school and use it in the development class.

Comment: How do you pass a class into a superclass?? Because I have never done that before and tried looking it up on the internet, but didn't help. Sorry for late response I thought I would figure it out with those hints by myself.